# Suma de valores de una misma clave en Javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto

Buen día comunidad.

Tengo un problema, básico a lo mejor. Es la suma de los valores de una misma clave y agruparlos por otra clave. Les dejo un ejemplo.
Dos objetos.

```
{
 comision: 30,
 Nombre: "CASTILLO ALBERTO",
 generado: 40,
 tipo: "CAMIONETA",
 id: 476
}
,
{
 comision: 10,
 Nombre: "CASTILLO ALBERTO",
 generado: 20,
 tipo: "CAMIONETA",
 id: 476
}
,
{
 comision: 30,
 Nombre: "HERNAN ALEJANDRO",
 generado: 40,
 tipo: "COMPACTO",
 id: 350
}
```

y de resultado estoy buscando algo como esto:

```
476{
     comisión: 40,
     generado: 60,
     Nombre: CASTILLO ALBERTO,
     Tipo: { 
         CAMIONETA: 2
     }
}

350{
     comisión: 30,
     generado: 40,
     Nombre: HERNAN ALEJANDRO,
     Tipo: { 
         COMPACTO: 1
     }
}
```

Espero sea lo mas claro posible. Espero su apoyo.

Comment: ¿Los datos están en un arreglo o en un JSON? ¿Qué es lo que has intentado?

Comment: Si la respuesta es válida y te ha servido, por favor, márcala como válida para que otros usuarios puedan saber que te funcionó.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que no sería necesario ese array temporal; lo que sí se puede hacer directamente es lo que comenta @IgnacioTorres, y utilizar `.reduce()` para ello:

```js
const datos = [
 { comision: 30, Nombre: "CASTILLO ALBERTO", generado: 40, tipo: "CAMIONETA", id: 476 },
 { comision: 10, Nombre: "CASTILLO ALBERTO", generado: 20, tipo: "CAMIONETA", id: 476 },
 { comision: 30, Nombre: "HERNAN ALEJANDRO", generado: 40, tipo: "COMPACTO", id: 350 }
];

const res = datos.reduce((acc, curr, index) => {
//  console.log('CURR: ', curr);
//  console.log('PREV: ', acc);
  if(curr.id in acc) {
    return {
      ...acc,
      [curr.id]: {
        comision: acc[curr.id].comision + curr.comision,
        generado: acc[curr.id].generado + curr.generado,
        Nombre: curr.Nombre,
        Tipo: {
          ...acc[curr.id].Tipo,
          [curr.tipo]: (acc[curr.id].Tipo[curr.tipo])
            ? acc[curr.id].Tipo[curr.tipo] + 1
            : 1
        }
      }
    };
  } else {
    return {
        ...acc,
      [curr.id]: {
        comision: curr.comision,
        generado: curr.generado,
        Nombre: curr.Nombre,
        Tipo: { [curr.tipo]: 1 }
      }
    };
  }
}, {});

console.log('Resultado: ', res);
```

Cualquier duda puedes utilizar los comentarios.

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que esos objetos se encuentran en un array, lo que podrias hacer es extraer todos los objetos que contengan el mismo id, es decir, sacarlos de ese array y colocarlos en uno nuevo.

Hasta este punto tendrias una array nuevo en el cual todos tienen la misma clave id (el mismo valor).

Luego solo quedaria utilizar array.reduce(), realizar dentro del mismo las sumas que sean necesarias y que devuelva un objeto con el resultado de las mismas, y solo quedaria agregar este objeto al array del principio.